# How to connect an iOS to Svn server from Xcode 5.1?

Tags: objective-c, svn, ios7, xcode5.1

Hi I m trying to configure server to Xcode while creating a iOS Project using Xcode 5.1

But I m getting below error:

"Connection Failed"

-Failed to establish a connection to server "myremoveServer/iOSSvnSampleApp". try
  entering the server address again

My server address is working fine with web

Can any one help me to push the Xcode project to SVN ??

Comment: Please post the output of `svn info`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this using Below links which provides clear explanation of configuring svn with Xcode

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Subversion-on-Mac-OS-X